# How to serve a REST API on Heroku

Tags: javascript, rest, heroku

I've built a REST API that works well if I host it locally. I followed this tutorial:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

How can I serve this on heroku or any other online platform so my app can execute CURL commands?

Here is the code I used:

https://github.com/taboada92/wham

Thanks

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/start

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script) to your project so heroku will know what to execute. If are new to Heroku + Node, I suggest going through the [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction)